# How to remove vertical plotlines on highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Suppose I add some vertical lines labeling with different names. Now I want to delete any line by clicking on the line. How do I do that...someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried repotting the graph on click and changing the setting to without the plot line?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your point. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: You want to delete the label that corresponds to the line you click on too, right?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread the question. You want to remove a series of data when you click on it, right? How many series will you have in one chart?

Comment: yeah thats right...no. of series will be as many as I add. First of all, lets take only one vertical plotline:

http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/RWCua/

Now delete the line(My Marker).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do to click a plotLine and have it instantly removed:

In the xAxis config, add a plotLine with a `click` event:

```
xAxis: {
    plotLines: [{ // mark the weekend
        id: 'plotLine1',
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4),
        events: {
            click: function(e) {
                this.axis.removePlotLine(this.id)
            }
        }
    }],
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    // one day
    type: 'datetime'
},
```

Here is a fiddle to show it work: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JA2gy/2/)

To get rid of the grid lines, you can just color them `transparent` inside the `yAxis` config:

```
yAxis: {
    ...
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
}
```

**Edit for new Question:** To remove the lines in this example, you can just add the event config to the new plotLines - like this:

```
// Inside chart event click function:
    chart.addPlotLine({
        value: event.xAxis[0].value,
        color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
        width: 2,

        // added label to id so the id is unique:
        id: 'vertLine_'+label,
        zIndex: 9999,

        // added plotLine event click - same as before.
        events: {
            click: function(e) {
                this.axis.removePlotLine(this.id);
            }
        },
        label : {
            text : label
        }
    });
```

Also, it looks like you're trying to make the chart NOT add a label if there is no text entered by the prompt. To do this, I would recommend adding a condition `&& label != ''` to your if-statement so in total it looks like `if(label!=null && label != '')`. I got this tip from [This site](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/canceled.htm).

Here is the updated fiddle: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3AqM7/3/).

Note: to successfully click on the line every time, aim for the left side. Idk why, but this worked better for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: ok...its fine but if I use dynamic data and if the id is not predefined then what to do. This code may solve the series deletion problem but how to remove vertical and horizontal PLOTLINE?

Comment: I added how to get rid of grid lines - just coloring them white. And good call, I'll work on getting rid of the plotline [not series] tomorrow! Sorry I misread the Q

Comment: @Poles - check updated answer. Now when you click on a plotLine, it should remove itself! The example shows a vertical plotLine, but the same idea should apply to horizontal plotLines too.

Comment: Its working, but can you remove this lines drawn by clicking on the chart...example: http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/3AqM7/1/

Comment: @Poles yep, I updated the answer and your fiddle to show this new solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also catch click event by [custom-events plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) and destroy SVG element (line+label)